# c++ vector element wise division

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to some simple calculation in C++, and I did it with nested for loop which is okay.

```
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_1(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_2(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_3(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_4(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_5(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_6(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> roi_7(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
     
    std::vector<int16_t> numerator(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<int16_t> denominator(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    std::vector<float_t> phi(ROI_WIDTH * ROI_HEIGHT);
    
    memcpy(&roi_1[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_2[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_3[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_4[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_5[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_6[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    memcpy(&roi_7[row*ROI_WIDTH], &ptr[(row+ROI_OFFSET_Y)*stride_pixels + ROI_OFFSET_X], ROI_WIDTH * sizeof(int16_t));
    
    //Calculate the numerator and denominator and phase angle...
    for (unsigned int m = 0; m < ROI_HEIGHT ; m++)
    {
        for(unsigned int n = 0; n < ROI_WIDTH ; n++)
        {
           numerator[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] = C2 * roi_2[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] - C4 * roi_4[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] + roi_6[m * ROI_WIDTH + n];
           denominator[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] = C3 * roi_3[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] - C5 * roi_5[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] + roi_7[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] - roi_1[m * ROI_WIDTH + n];
           phi[m * ROI_WIDTH + n] = atan2(numerator[m * ROI_WIDTH + n], denominator[m * ROI_WIDTH + n]);
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to do the calculation with vector, but the following code did not provide the same result? Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
    transform(numerator.begin(), numerator.end(), numerator.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return C2*roi_2[i] - C4*roi_4[i] + roi_6[i];});
    transform(denominator.begin(), denominator.end(), denominator.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return C3*roi_3[i] - C5*roi_5[i] + roi_7[i] - roi_1[i];});
    transform(phi.begin(), phi.end(), phi.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return atan2(numerator[i], denominator[i]);});
```

Comment: Your first code sample does a whole lot of things you haven't described.   For example, what are `ptr`, `row`, and `stride_pixels`?     If you want to get reasonable answers, you need to provide all necessary information (otherwise people have to guess) and eliminate code that is not relevant to your problem (people can't reliably guess which irrelevant code is actually irrelevant).   Read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`unary_op` of `std::transform` gets input values, not indices. I think it gets `i = 0` in all cases. You may pre-fill the vectors with indices.

```
std::iota(numerator.begin(), numerator.end(), 0);
std::iota(denominator.begin(), denominator.end(), 0);
std::iota(numerator.begin(), numerator.end(), 0);

std::transform(phi.begin(), phi.end(), numerator.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return C2*roi_2[i] - C4*roi_4[i] + roi_6[i];});
std::transform(denominator.begin(), denominator.end(), denominator.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return C3*roi_3[i] - C5*roi_5[i] + roi_7[i] - roi_1[i];});
std::transform(phi.begin(), phi.end(), phi.begin(), [&](const auto &i){return atan2(numerator[i], denominator[i]);});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Unfortunately, it is not working yet as I am writing the data to file but it fails to read.